# How to get code coverage on C# record setters with positional constructor

Tags: c#, code-coverage, record

I noticed that my C# Records with positional constructor syntax are reporting no code coverage in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise. For example, a record is defined as:

`public record BallPoint(int X, int Y, int Z);`

And the test:

```
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var sut = new BallPoint(1, 2, 3);

            Assert.Equal(1, sut.X);
            Assert.Equal(2, sut.Y);
            Assert.Equal(3, sut.Z);
        }
```

Then the coverage shows internal setters that are not covered:

[image: Code coverage view]

How can I get 100% coverage of this Record?

Comment: Show us the constructor. Is it calling those set methods to load itself?

Comment: @HackSlash: It's a `record` type with a primary constructor. The constructor is already shown in the post. It will initialize the `X`, `Y`, and `Z` properties from the parameters. End of story.

Comment: @avenue19: It looks like code coverage hasn't kept up with the times. The constructor IL *is* calling the `set_*` accessor methods.

Comment: @avenue19: As HackSlash and I have concluded, this test case is pointless because you're essentially testing that the compiler is working. You don't need to do that. Microsoft has extensive test cases that already do this.

Answer (score 2):

The code coverage libraries haven't caught up with the c# records.

To do that properly for a record you will need to use the `with` keyword.

Here is the proper way to do it for an immutable record:

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void BallPoint_IsARecord()
    {
        //Arrange
        var sut = new BallPoint(1, 2, 3);

        //Act
        sut = sut with {
            X = 4,
            Y = 5,
            Z = 6
        };

        //Assert
        Assert.Equal(4, sut.X);
        Assert.Equal(5, sut.Y);
        Assert.Equal(6, sut.Z);
    }
```

I suggest you always use different values in the `with` clause to ensure the original values were not propagated to the new instance.

The code above will test your whole record in one test (the constructor, the getters, and the setters).

Answer (score -1):

Change your test to call the set methods.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var sut = new BallPoint();
        sut.X = 1;
        sut.Y = 2;
        sut.Z = 3;

        Assert.Equal(1, sut.X);
        Assert.Equal(2, sut.Y);
        Assert.Equal(3, sut.Z);
    }
```

Alternatively, you could change the constructor to explicitly call the set methods.

Comment: Positional parameters of primary constructors are init-only properties and cannot be assigned in this way. Since they're constructor parameters, they're required there and therefore it's pointless (either redundant or contradictory) to assign them in an object initializer.

Comment: @madreflection wouldn't it also be pointless to attempt to test them?

Comment: Yes. This test case is boils down to testing the compiler, not user code.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I was confused. I assumed we were talking about a custom class.